# Tansmission plugin permissions setup for FreeNAS 9.3

Tags: transmission

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in an NFS share with a FreeNAS 9.3 setup.

I basically want to run the Transmission plugin on the FreeNAS with full permissions.

The NFS share works just fine, with add and delete files from Ubuntu of the whole share `/mnt/FreeNAS/Dataset`. But when I use the Transmission (192.168.1.2:9091) and download a torrent to the Download folder `/mnt/FreeNAS/Dataset/Transmission`, I get in red "Error:permission denied" `/mnt/FreeNAS/Dataset/Transmission/(torrent.file)` in the Transmission web GUI.

I am lost what to do next. I have tried different things and always get the same error. Can you help?